# 'rzslider' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Hey I am trying to install rzslider but I have troubles to add a slider because the tag 'rzslider' is not known. I followed the steps in their github readme.

First I installed rzslider like this:

> npm i angularjs-slider

I also added typescript support like this:

> npm i @types/angular

then I imported the 'rzslider.js

> script src="/node_modules/angularjs-slider/dist/rzslider.js">

I did not added the css because they did it neither in their examples

Everything went fine but all I got is the error message that 'rzslider' is not a known element.

Do I have to add it like a module?

Comment: Yes you would have to have `angular.module('yourmodule', ['rzModule'])` at least

Comment: You cant just access files on the server like you do in php and others. You need to enable the file accessing

Comment: yeah i did that in my js module I defined my ng app in my html and in my js i did "var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['rzModule']);"

Comment: @JonasW. I dont want to access a file on the server I only want to load the js file in the same app. I thought this is possible with <script src="dateselection.js"></script>

Comment: Is this the rz slider you're referring to? http://embed.plnkr.co/Lf9wMjUWGnUlUF999YyL/

Comment: Yes this is the slider I try to implement sorry that I have not added a link to the question